# Calling postgres function with parameter in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a postgres function written in select_sql.sql file like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_vnf_func(IN vimid_i text) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
select * from vimzoneinfo where vimid=vimid_i;
END
$$language plpgsql;
```

And now I am calling this function from python script like:

```
import os
os.system("sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/psql --d vnflafdb -f /tmp/select_sql.sql")
vim_id = "vimid1"
os.system("sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/psql --d vnflafdb -c 'SELECT select_vnf_func(vim_id::text);'")
```

But I am getting error: 
ERROR: column vim_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT select_vnf_func(vim_id);

Here 'vim_id' is the parameter I am trying to pass to the function. And 'vimid' is the actual column in table.
When there are no parameter in function call it works.
Please suggest.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If you need to call Postgres from Python, use one of the [libraries](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python) available for that purpose.

Comment: Yes...but somehow in my production environment psycopg2 is not available. Any other library you can suggest?

Comment: There are several linked from that page. But you'd need to install any of them, just the same as you need to install psycopg2. Why can't you do that?

Comment: That is the problem, I can't go for any installation on production server...that is the reason I am trying this solution.

Comment: @user2594191 Psycopg is client software. Install it in your local machine, the same that runs Python.

Comment: Make sure all users have it installed also if you are sharing scripts.